# Deploy to Production: Why is CloudKit deleting Subscription Types?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I'm in the midst of deploying changes from the development environment to the production environment. When I go into the iCloud developer dashboard, navigate to the container, and select "Deploy Schema to Production" I notice that included in the changes is a deletion of Subscription Types.

(These Subscription Types are created by `CKQuerySubscription` and they are indeed present in both my development schema and production schema. Again, this is an update to the production environment.)

I looked through the other apps I'm working with, and all attempts to "Deploy Schema to Production" include a deletion of every single Subscription Type.

What's up with this?

Should I be concerned that deploying to production will break existing `CKQuerySubscription` infrastructure for our paying customers?

Did Apple deprecate the need for subscriptions to be included in the schema? (`CKDatabaseSubscriptions` do not need to be in the schemas at all.)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay in the "Deploy Schema to Production" dialogue. Despite presenting Subscription Types as being marked for deletion, the Subscription Type was not deleted from the Production environment.

I did deploy the schema to production and I did confirm that the Subscription Types remained active in the Production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have those subscriptions already on production?
If yes then these subscriptions are only removed from deployment to production they will not be removed from production.

Edit
Sorry for late response to your comment.

If you have changes to your subscription types they will be overwritten not deleted, if you don't have changes than nothing will happen they won't be deleted from CloudKit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand – Yes, the Subscription Types exist in both development and production environments. What does it mean that they are marked for deletion?

Comment: Re: Edit -> is that documented anywhere? I was horrified at the prospect of breaking sync for all of our customers by deleting Subscription Types in the schema.